# Root android apps to Tor

Tags: android

I have an android and I can only use Tor through orbot to browse the Internet. Is there a way I can run all of my apps through Tor so that every app I use on my phone will be secured and untraceable?

Comment: My phone is samung galaxy y s5360.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. This is build-in in the Orbot options. Just open the settings and scroll to the down side. There you can choose to run all your apps through Tor or just some of them.

Comment: I'm asking for my friend. I have an iPhone so I can't see specifically. Is the option for EVERY app? Like texting as well? Or just certain apps?

Comment: When you clik on `Tor Everything` option all the traffic goes through Tor. If you want to have secure texting. You should use TextSexure for SMS or for chat - ChatSecure or something similar with OTR encryption.

Comment: Yes, i've seen the option for route-all-to-tor some time ago, but as Kasmetski says, this is not ideal security if you consider your plain-text data's vulnerability in a big-nosed tor-exit.